# Correct interface for one time only Enumeration (i.e. a "stream")

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

I've got stream like data structure, that can be enumerated over once.

Currently, I've got a function that returns a `IEnumerator` which internally contains this structure. This enumerator can not be `reset()` of course.

This approach means that clients can not attempt to enumerate over the stream twice, as they don't have access to the underlying structure, only a non-resetable enumerator to it.

However, I've noticed that the `foreach` statement requires an `IEnumerable` implementation.

I hesitate a offering an `IEnumerable` interface implementation, because implicit in the contract of `IEnumerable` seems to be that one should be able to enumerate over the `IEnumerable` multiple times, however my structure does not allow that. Basically there can only be one enumerator to my structure ever.

I've even gave my enumerator have a private copy constructor to ensure this.

But because of using `IEnumerator`, not `IEnumerable`, it seems I lose the `foreach` syntax for example.

Is what I'm doing the best approach, or am I using completely the wrong abstraction? Is there a "Stream" interface that better encapulates what I'm trying to achieve? I notice there are "Stream" data types, but they deal with bytes. I need my stream to be parameterised over "T" however.

My project is coding for Windows XP boxes unfortunately, so I'd prefer answers compatible with .NET 2.0, but if that's not possible answers relating to later .NET versions is okay, at least it might offer some inspiration and be useful to future readers of this question.

Comment: The resetable contract is defined on IEnumerator, so you're already breaking the contract. I don't see how adding `: IEnumerable<T>` makes it any worse.

Comment: I'm curious as to why it cannot be reset, actually.

Comment: From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx

"The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException."

Comment: By twenty seconds :p

Comment: It can't be reset as it's a stream of data which is processed and then dropped on the fly. Keeping it all for a reset() I have no intent to use will result in it eventually running the system out of memory.

Comment: This is starting to smell more like a Reader type contract. Instead of getting an enumerator as a second object, just call ReadObject() (or similar) over and over until it returns null.

Comment: Can you link to the Reader style interface so I can have a look?

Comment: It's not an interface, it's a pattern. Perhaps the most basic example is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx

> The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException.